# Error in make while installing ndiswrapper

Tags: package-management, make, ndiswrapper

I have problems installing ndiswrapper, I can not run `make`, it throws the following error:

```
remiii @ Remiii-HP: ~ / ndiswrapper-1.58rc1 $ make
make-C utils
make [1]: Entering directory '/ home/remiii/ndiswrapper-1.58rc1/utils »
make [1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make [1]: Leaving directory '/ home/remiii/ndiswrapper-1.58rc1/utils »
make-C driver
make [1]: Entering directory '/ home/remiii/ndiswrapper-1.58rc1/driver »
Makefile: 36: *** Can not find kernel version in / lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/build, is it configured?. Alto.
make [1]: Leaving directory '/ home/remiii/ndiswrapper-1.58rc1/driver »
make: *** [driver] Error 2
```

Help please.

Result :

root@Remiii-HP:~/ndiswrapper-1.58rc1# sudo lshw -c network
  *-network

```
   descripción: Ethernet interface
   producto: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
   fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   id físico: 0
   información del bus: pci@0000:06:00.0
   nombre lógico: eth0
   versión: 05
   serie: 84:34:97:81:a1:16
   tamaño: 100Mbit/s
   capacidad: 100Mbit/s
   anchura: 64 bits
   reloj: 33MHz
   capacidades: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 
mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuración: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-
NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw ip=192.168.1.35 latency=0 link=yes 
multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       recursos: irq:46 ioport:2000(size=256) memoria:f0204000-f0204ff 

memoria:f0200000-
        f0203fff

  *-network NO RECLAMADO
       descripción: Network controller
       producto: Ralink corp.
       fabricante: Ralink corp.
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:07:00.0
       versión: 00
       anchura: 32 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuración: latency=0
       recursos: memoria:f0110000-f011ffff
```

root@Remiii-HP:~/ndiswrapper-1.58rc1# rfkill list all

```
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

1: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

remiii@Remiii-HP:~/ndiswrapper-1.58rc1$ lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 14h Processor Root Complex
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device 9808
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Wrestler HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6250/6310]
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB XHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson SMBus Controller (rev 14)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson Azalia Controller (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:15.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device 43a0
00:15.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device 43a1
00:15.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device 43a2
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 0 
(rev 43)
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 6
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 5
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 7
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express ard 
Reader (rev 01)
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
07:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. Device 3290
07:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. Device 3298
```

Comment: are you sure you need `ndiswrapper`? It is most less suggested most discouraged option in present days. What is your wireless card, include some details (`lspci`/ `lsusb`)  so that we can help

Comment: open a terminal, execute following commands one by one. These will give your hardware details. Copy those output, edit your question and include them.Commands  `lspci`, `sudo lshw -c network`, `rfkill list all`

Comment: Ok (Y) ^^^^^^^^